# $\int\limits_{0}^{1}(\prod\limits_{r=1}^{n}(x+r))(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k})dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

The value of $\int\limits_{0}^{1}(\prod\limits_{r=1}^{n}(x+r))(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k})dx$ is equal to

$(A)n\hspace{1cm}(B)n!\hspace{1cm}(C)(n+1)!\hspace{1cm}(D)n.n!$

I tried:$\int\limits_{0}^{1}(\prod\limits_{r=1}^{n}(x+r))(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k})dx$=$\int\limits_{0}^{1}(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)(\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+2}+......+\frac{1}{x+n})dx$=$\int\limits_{0}^{1}(x+2)(x+3)...(x+n)+(x+1)(x+3)...(x+n)dx$

I cannot solve it further.Is my approach wrong,I am stuck.What is the right way to solve,Please help...

Comment: Hint: Let $p(x) = \prod_{r=1}^n(x+r)$, the expression $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x+k}$ in the integrand is equal to $\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)}$.

Comment: @achillehui,yes i got it,thanks a lot.

Comment: use induction to prove that equals n.n!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $$A=\prod_{k=1}^n(x+k)$$ Take logarithms of both sides $$\log(A)=\sum_{k=1}^n \log(x+k)$$ Compute the derivative $$\frac {A'}A=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{x+k}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 3):

Differentiate $\prod_{k=1}^n(x+k)$ with respect to $x$, and you get the integrand. So the answer is $(n+1)!-n!=n\cdot n!$.

Answer (score 3):

First let us make a common denominator for the rationals under the sum sign
$$
\left(\prod\limits_{r=1}^n (x+r)\right)
\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x+k} \right)\\
=
\left(\prod\limits_{r=1}^n (x+r)\right)
\left(
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n
\frac{\prod\limits_{r=1,r\neq k}^n (x+r)}
{\prod\limits_{r=1}^n (x+r)}
\right)
=
\left(
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n
\prod\limits_{r=1,r\neq k}^n (x+r)
\right)
=
\frac{d}{dx}
\left(
\prod\limits_{r=1}^n (x+r)
\right),
$$

where we used the product rule for the last equal sign.
Now can you complete your exercise on your own?